# need to crc32 integer column and substr the result

Tags: mysql

I need to grab the integer value of column `id`, use `crc32()` on it, and then `substr` the first 2 characters.

This is what I have in mind:

`SELECT SUBSTR(CRC32(id),0,2) FROM table LIMIT 10;`

The problem is, the following returns an empty value for each row which leads me to believe that `substr()` is not doing its job.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try **LEFT( CRC32(  'id' ) , 2 )** function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CRC32(id),1,2) FROM table LIMIT 10;
```

Enjoy!